# Django: Passing argument via image to get a filtered view in next page

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am having a big confusion right now and can't any good answers online about my issue.
What I am trying to do is, to let the users click on an image. I have 52 different images on my page and by clicking on the image i want to pass an int between 1-53 (52 is missing) in order to get a filtered view.

**models.py**

```
class CentroidCount(models.Model):
    id_centroid_count = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_observation = models.ForeignKey('Observation', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_observation', blank=True, null=True)
    step = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    centroid = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    count = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'centroid_count'
    ordering = ['id_observation', 'step', 'centroid']

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('centroid-detail', args=[str(self.id_centroid_count)])

def __str__(self):
    return 'Observation: %s' % (self.id_observation)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('', views.index, name='index'),
   path('observations/', views.ObservationListView.as_view(), name='observations'),
]
```

views.py

```
class ObservationListView(generic.ListView):
model = CentroidCount
context_object_name = 'observation_list'
queryset = CentroidCount.objects.filter(centroid__in=[]).order_by('id_observation').values_list('id_observation', flat=True).distinct() 
template_name = 'centroid_webapp/observation_list.html'

def get_queryset(self):
    return CentroidCount.objects.filter(centroid__in=[2]).order_by('id_observation').values_list('id_observation', flat=True).distinct()
```

and the image part of the html

```
     <div class="col-sm">
        <img src="{% static 'images/1.png'%}" class='img-fluid' alt='Responsive image'>
     </div>
```

What I still don't understand that is how can this be done dynamically. What I do have now is a static page that is filterint out all "id_observations" with the number 2. But I would like to pass the  with the image via the url to the view.

Hope I was able to give a good enough picture of the situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

Create a hyperlinked image in the **template**:

```
<div class="col-sm">
    <a href="\myview\[id]"> <!-- pass the image id -->
        <img src="{% static 'images/1.png'%}" class='img-fluid' alt='Responsive image'>
    </a>
</div>
```

Also create the url in the **urls.py**:

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('', views.index, name='index'),
   path('observations/', views.ObservationListView.as_view(), name='observations'),
   path('myview/<int:img_id>', views.MyView(), name='myview'), #call the view
]
```

And create the view where you want the image id:

```
def MyView(request, img_id):
    """your code"""
   return HttpResponse('Hello World!') #return the response you want to
```

Comment: so far so good, it looks like the links are working as requested, but i am still struggeling with passing the argument from the html to the view. let's say i define the int as img_id, where is it passed to the view?

Comment: yes you get the `img_id` into the view. see I have passed two parameters in the above view. First the `request` and another one is the `img_id`.